# Is there other way to minimize multiple selection like attached?

Tags: selection, multi-selection

Is there other way to minimize multiple selection like attached?

These are admin roles, in each role, there are options that limits/allow the users to control task.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want to discourage the user to make many selections? or do you mean to minimize the list?

Comment: Please add more detail as to the exact problem

Comment: It's good that you added an illustration, That's a great help. But you can see from these comments that people want a bit more detail about the context and limitations.

Comment: For me it's not clear what you want to achieve and why, could you explaine it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to minimise multiple selections (e.g. not have a user select 25+ check boxes) but want to retain the option to it might be worth grouping available tasks. From looking through there seem to be similar functions throughout so you can group them to the subject e.g.:

- Agents.Brand_Management

  1. Favicons:

     - Upload
     - Show
     - Delete
     - Apply
  2. Logo:

     - Upload
     - Show
     - Delete
     - Apply

Then you can retain the option for users to select/deselect aspects of these sub groups if needed. That being said it totally depends on what the most common kind of permissions are. So if they usually have full reign to upload/show/delete/apply favicon then the above would work really well. However if users are often only allowed to upload favions/logos etc and not delete them - then perhaps it may be worth setting groups based on what the action is e.g.:

- Agents.Brand_Management

  1. Upload:

     - Favicons
     - Logos
     - etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to eliminate it before it got to this problem which, I guess, you are trying to solve technically.

**I would reconsider the model.**

According to the current model there exist thousands to millions possible combinations, depending on the role. Do you really think they will all be used? I guess not. Usually, the privileges per role are fixed, so you have few roles in the system and the users are mapped to one or more role.

So start thinking about the most probable combinations that will be used. For example, it is most possible that one who is allowed to allocate payments will also be allowed to unallocate payments. Keep on eliminating impossible/rare combinations until you end with a list of maximum 2-3 sub-roles per role.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very practical situation which we come across. Host of items to be shown. Sometimes, we face the challenge of just adding the itmes, due to the business logic or other reasons. To simplify or minimize the items, I would consider having the controls, like shown below, a list box with check box that contains all the check box options and shows only at the click.

[image]

After the user selects the options, the choices will be listed below the drop down. This will help in seeing the selections already made. In case, one wants to change, simply click the cross or delete next to the choice and/or reselect the items. The tick on the collapsed drop down shows the selections have been made by the user.

[image]

So, all in all, it will save a lot of space. And

Comment: I like this view.  I'd consider combining this "tag-like" view with some ability to search for ones to select too.

Answer (score 0):

I would just convert each of those roles into a chosen jquery plugin.. https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

This will save space and also if you want to minimize the number of selections, you could something like this..

```
$(".chosenjquery-select").chosen({ max_selected_options: 10 });
```

It is a drop down, a multi select, a text box, an auto complete all in one.

There is a lot of customizations you can do (review all cases in the first link) according to your requirement.